# Chicken parmesan high carb

Tags: nutrient-composition

I looked at well-known restaurant nutrition guides and noted that their chicken Parmesan dishes always seem to be high in carbohydrates and sugar. On par with ravioli and ice-cream.

How is it being prepared that is would be so high? I'm thinking plenty of added sugar to the marinara sauce?

Comment: You understand that pasta is primarily starch, right?

Comment: @Sneftel I was under impression that this only included main entree.  Let me re-check.

Comment: the carbs likely come from the breading -- flour and breadcrumbs.  Sugars from the tomato sauce (for which you might be able to find a less bad version of)